# A Delete-proof way to get the index of a table row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this nice and neat way of loading posts for my blog website to fit specified page:

```
  $end = $count - ($page * $ppp); //count = select max(id) from art;
  $start = $count- ($page * $ppp) - ($ppp-1);

  $nxtpage = $page +1; //this is set beforehand in case no posts exists
  $prvpage = $page == 0 ? 0 : $page -1;
  $sql = "SELECT
  a.id AS id,
  a.nazwa AS nazwa,
  a.data AS data,
  a.wstep AS wstep,
  a.imgs AS imgs,
  a.zdj AS zdj,
     GROUP_CONCAT(t.nazwa) all_tags
  FROM
     art a INNER JOIN tagart ta ON a.id = ta.id INNER JOIN tags t ON t.idt = ta.idt
   WHERE a.id BETWEEN $start AND $end
   GROUP BY a.id
   ORDER BY a.id desc";
```

This way I can load only a specified numer of posts depended by blogs page (pagination).
 There is a pretty big problem with it tho.
Lets say my client make a mistake like [writing BLACK PPL somewhere in one article](http://time.com/4245185/ihop-customers-black-ppl-receipt/) half a year ago, and now he has to delete it.

Or even better, has to delete about 10 posts from it. When middle posts are deleted, the whole alrorithm gets messed up, because it scans posts based it their ID.

So my question here for you is what better way of picking the posts I could use, that would always get the correct order of the posts?

Comment: Use `LIMIT` http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to implement your own way of doing `LIMIT`, which is a MySQL feature that handles pagination. Instead of manually defining your start and end ID's, you should be looking to order your posts and then only fetching the next `X` posts, no matter what their ID's are. Here's how you would do that

```
$start = ($page - 1) * $ppp;
$sql = "SELECT
    a.id AS id,
    a.nazwa AS nazwa,
    a.data AS data,
    a.wstep AS wstep,
    a.imgs AS imgs,
    a.zdj AS zdj,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.nazwa) all_tags
FROM
    art a INNER JOIN tagart ta ON a.id = ta.id INNER JOIN tags t ON t.idt = ta.idt
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT $start,$ppp";
```

LIMIT is used as either

```
LIMIT 5 #Fetch first 5 items
```

or

```
LIMIT 5,10 #Starting from the 5th item, fetch the next 10 items
```

Comment: I did know about LIMIT, but didn't about the "_starting from nth item _" parameter. I'll try it asa I get back on my machine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `max(id)` to determine the number of posts, use `count(id)` or `count(*)` to actually count them. If a post gets deleted, the count can take that into account.

In the select query use `limit` to select the range of posts to show.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, you should not be relying on MAX(id) to count the number of records.
I would just use a separate count query to get the count. It's simple and relatively inexpensive:

```
SELECT COUNT (id) FROM art
```

And as others have already mentioned, use LIMIT to paginate instead of limiting by id.